# Is there a way to write read/write chunks in the feather format on Python?

Tags: python, dataformat, feather

I am pretty new to python and databases. I am trying to write my dataset in the feather format. The dataset is large and segmented, I want to store my data in chunks and retrieve only certain chunks when I need them. Would this be possible ? I appreciate any advice, Thank you!

I was looking through the API for feather in pyarrow, I found that the [write function](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.feather.write_feather.html#pyarrow.feather.write_feather) allows you to specify chunksize, but I haven't been able to find out how to read the chunks or query specific chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. It's a little hard to see because pyarrow sometimes calls its format 'feather', sometimes calls it 'arrow', and sometimes 'ipc'. The simpler method is `pyarrow.feather.read_table,` which you've find; but to access individual chunks you'll want to instead use `pyarrow.ipc.open_file`. That returns [an object that can read one batch at a time](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.ipc.RecordBatchFileReader.html#pyarrow.ipc.RecordBatchFileReader).

```py
reader = pyarrow.ipc.open_file('my_file.feather')
first_batch = reader.get_batch(0)
fourth_batch = reader.get_batch(3)
```

Note also though that when you use `feather.read_table()`, it doesn't actually load the whole table into memory; instead it use memory mapping to make it faster to work with but leaves it on disk. That means that for non-enormous datasets (up to a gigabyte or two) it's often fine to load the whole thing at once.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out! Right now I am using the to_batches(self, max_chunksize=None) method of a Pyarrow Table after I read in the table and then get different batches.