# Process killed when reading big feather file with pandas due to OOM

Tags: python, pandas, out-of-memory, feather

I'm trying to read a big feather file and my process get's killed:

```bash
gerardo@hal9000:~/Projects/Morriello$ du -h EtOH.feather 
5.3G    EtOH.feather
```

I'm using pandas and pyarrow, here are the versions

```bash
gerardo@hal9000:~/Projects/Morriello$ pip freeze | grep "pandas\|pyarrow"
pandas==2.2.1
pyarrow==15.0.0
```

When I try to load the dataset into a dataframe I just get the process killed:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.read_feather("EtOH.feather", dtype_backend='pyarrow')
Killed
```

I'm on linux and I'm using `Python 3.12`, on a machine with 16Gb of RAM.

I saw the process get's killed due to an Out Of Memory error.

```
Out of memory: Killed process 918058 (ipython) total-vm:24890996kB, anon-rss:8455548kB, file-rss:640kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:17228kB oom_score_adj:100
```

I've also trying reading it in batches as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76038997/is-there-a-way-to-write-read-write-chunks-in-the-feather-format-on-python) and by @David but the process still gets killed:

```
In [4]: import pyarrow

In [5]: reader = pyarrow.ipc.open_file('./EtOH.feather')

In [6]: first_batch = reader.get_batch(0)
```

How do I read the file in this case? And if I manage to read it, would there been noticeable advantages in converting it to a `parquet` format?

Comment: This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76038997/is-there-a-way-to-write-read-write-chunks-in-the-feather-format-on-python

Comment: How much RAM do you have in the computer running this  code?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy 16gb

Comment: It seems like this gets killed when it is only using 8GB of memory: `anon-rss:8455548kB`. Is something else on this computer using lots of memory?